# Material Bottom Tabs Navigator Label and Icon not aligning in a row

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I'm attempting to set the icon and label side by side in the Material Bottom tabs navigator, I have looked into the docs and it says to use `tabBarLabelPosition` as `beside-icon` although I couldn't achieve any success. I'm using react navigation 6.x.

My code:

```
return (
    <Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarShowLabel: true,
        tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#000',
          height: 2,
        },
tabBarStyle: {
          tabBarLabelPosition: 'besides-icon',
        },
        tabBarLabelPosition: 'besides-icon',
        tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
          if (route.name === 'Feed') {
            return <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>Feed</Text>;
          } else if (route.name === 'Short') {
            return <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>Short</Text>;
          } else if (route.name === 'Tag') {
            return <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>Tag</Text>;
          }
        },
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
          if (route.name === 'Feed') {
            return <FeedSVG width={14} height={14} style={{ width: '100%', marginRight: 5 }} />;
          } else if (route.name === 'Short') {
            return <VideoShortSVG width={14} height={14} style={{ marginRight: 5 }} />;
          } else if (route.name === 'Tag') {
            return <TagUnionSVG width={14} height={14} style={{ marginRight: 5 }} />;
          }
        },
      })}
    >
      <Screen key="ProfilePosts" name="Feed" component={Posts} />
      <Screen key="ProfileReels" name="Short" component={Reels} />
      <Screen key="ProfileTag" name="Tag" component={Tag} />
    </Navigator>
```

Result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Implement to this type of design you want to make custom it.
here I share with you some points which you can implement easily.

==> First you need to do `tabBarShowLabel:false`.

==> Then you need apply Styles in `TabBarIcon`.

```
tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
          if (route.name === 'Feed') {
            return (
                <View
                 style={{
                     flexDirection: "row",
                     alignItems: "center",
                     marginRight: 5,
                  }}
                >
                <FeedSVG width={14} height={14} style={{ width: '100%', marginRight: 5 }} />
               <Text>{"Feed"}</Text>
         </View>
        );
          } else if (route.name === 'Short') {
            return (
                <View
                 style={{
                     flexDirection: "row",
                     alignItems: "center",
                     marginRight: 5,
                  }}
                >
                <VideoShortSVG width={14} height={14} style={{ marginRight: 5 }} />;
               <Text>{"Short"}</Text>
         </View>
        );
          } else if (route.name === 'Tag') {
            return (
                <View
                 style={{
                     flexDirection: "row",
                     alignItems: "center",
                     marginRight: 5,
                  }}
                >
                <TagUnionSVG width={14} height={14} style={{ marginRight: 5 }} />;
               <Text>{"Tag"}</Text>
         </View>
        );
          }
        },
```

Like this you can implement this.

`* You can customize the code also using the making custom component for tabBarIcon`